# How to mock web worker for testing in react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, web-worker

I'm creating a web worker like this:

```
const getWebWorker = () => {
  let worker;
  if (typeof worker === 'undefined') {
    worker = new Worker('worker.js');
  }
  return worker;
};
```

Then I am calling the function like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getWebWorker().onmessage = (event) => {
    setWorkerData(event.data);
  };
}, []);
```

The actually worker.js file is under the public folder and postMessage's an object.

I'm using the react testing library/jest to test. When I run `yarn run test` I get the error `ReferenceError: Worker is not defined` at `worker = new Worker('worker.js');`.

I understand that I need to mock the worker, I'm just confused on how to.

What do I name the mock file in the `__mock__` folder?

What would mocking the worker even look like?

Is there anything I have to do in the ____.test.js file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Afaik that is not supported by jest btw. [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) are a [browser thing](https://jsfiddle.net/e0vxjd74/). Use e2e tests instead.

```
if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
  alert("Your have web worker support! (Webbrowser)")
} else {
  console.warn("You have no web worker support (node)")
}
```

> Jest uses a JSDOM environment by default, which means it doesn't
> support Workers. This means it is impossible to test code that
> requires both NodeJS functionality and Web Workers.
> [jsdom-worker](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker)

[jsdom-worker](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker) tried to bring web workers to jest, but that had no update since 2020 and seems to be unmaintained... btw there is a
[spin off](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerloader-jest-transformer) that is marked as experimental.

I had the same question and used e2e tests [playwright](https://playwright.dev/) to [test](https://github.com/stesee/BonReader/blob/main/playwright/integrationTest.spec.ts#L18) things where web workers are involved because I found no production ready way to mock workers.